# VS Code run in terminal with a hotkey

Tags: node.js, terminal, visual-studio-code

How to run active file by integrated terminal?

I set hotkey for `workbench.action.terminal.runActiveFile`

It works but not correct, cause launch path as command:

`C:\cwd>c:\cwd\app.js` but i need `C:\cwd>node app.js`

Comment: I think you are going to need the extension "code runner" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner  where you can tell it to run javascript files with node.

Comment: Thanks, i already use code runner, and it`s luggy.

Comment: There is a way to do it with a macro if you are interested.

Comment: Now see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082394/run-files-in-terminal-from-vs-code/55082505#55082505 - no need for a macro anymore to run the current file with node.js.