# Run files in terminal from VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there any VS Code shorcut that lets you run a file in the Windows terminal without writing the path of the file directly into the terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By `path` you mean the whole path i.e. the absolute path or your path to file with respect to the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question I think you can look into the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks). I guess you have to change your `task.json` accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "node '${file}'\u000D" }
  }
```

With whatever keybinding you wish.  See [Release notes: sendSequence and variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_integrated-terminal).

With vscode v1.32 you can sendSequence to the terminal using variables like ${file}, which is the current file.  If you want some other path there, replace ${file} with your pathname in the keybinding above.

In the above keybinding I just added `node` - replace that with whatever you need to run python files in the terminal.  Like whatever your setting is:  `"c:/python27/python.exe"` from `"python.pythonPath": "c:/python27/python.exe"`

The `\u000D` is a return so it runs automatically.

I added `'`s around the ${file} variable in case your file path has spaces in it,

like `c:Users\Some Directory\fileToRun`