# How can I set a hotkey to input a command in VS Code's terminal?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Is it possible to set a VS Code hotkey to input a command in the terminal?
I need to input <kbd>r</kbd> to hot reload my flutter app. and it'll be easier if I can have a hotkey for that.

I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch to terminal and input <kbd>r</kbd> myself, but I hope that there will be an easier way.

Comment: you can use the `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` command

Comment: See the dup and many others, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082505/836330.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) hinted in the comments, you can do this with the `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` keybinding command.

For official documentation, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_custom-sequence-keybindings.

Here's a template of what it might look like in your keybindings.json file:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO put something here
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "r" }
}
```

Note: If the keybinding you want to use is already in use, I believe you need to explicitly disable it. You search for existing keybindings in the keybindings UI and then delete/disable them there.

Here's a bit more excerpt from the above linked docs:

> This feature supports [variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).
>
> The `sendSequence` command only works with the `\u0000` format for using characters via their character code (not `\x00`). Read more about these hex codes and terminal sequences in the following resources:
>
> - [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
> - [List of C0 and C1 control codes](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts)